# How to identify "deictic center" for distinguishing "come" & "go"?

Tags: word-choice, grammar, word-usage, deixis

Read this paragraph from this [site](https://books.google.com.vn/books?id=BbUYXzwAyhUC&pg=PA146&lpg=PA146&dq=English%20grammar%20come%20and%20go%20deictic%20center&source=bl&ots=Eh5X0vF8yk&sig=8-dj4cgNQoHSrcJ1uWDMRW6npn8&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=English%20grammar%20come%20and%20go%20deictic%20center&f=false)
[image]

My question is:

**How to identify "deictic center" for distinguishing "come" & "go"?**

Let say I am at home & I say "**I am going to the zoo this evening**", so the "deictic center" in this case is my home & I move away my "deictic center".

But let say my friend Tom & I currently at my home & Tom said "**Are you Coming to the zoo to see the lion?**" & I said "**Ok, I am coming to the zoo this evening**". So, the "deictic center" in this case is "**the zoo**" & we move towards the "deictic center" (ie the zoo).

It feels like it is very arbitrary.

Note: See this [link](https://books.google.com.vn/books?id=lx7UAniLfJwC&pg=PA24&lpg=PA24&dq=deictic%20center%20%22come%22%20%26%20%22go%22%20grammar&source=bl&ots=_gKauOYWwK&sig=7pCE5J3OQFqb3A2WJPjpfyiuZ2I&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiqr_f7vInOAhWIj5QKHbHgDvIQ6AEILDAD#v=onepage&q=deictic%20center%20%22come%22%20%26%20%22go%22%20grammar&f=false), it said the selection of "deictic center" could be due to **sympathy** & **politeness**.

Comment: It's not the location being spoken of?

Comment: It is arbitrary. A speaker has the 'right' to choose the deictic center, just like an artist has the right to choose the perspective for his painting. There is freedom of expression in both. Instead of worrying about this so much, practice English with native speakers (99% of whom have never heard the word *deictic*) and pick up on how they say things. You will learn patterns and nuances.  Do you want to learn how native speakers actually speak, or worry yourself to death over something native speakers don't give a second thought about?

Comment: Two more things to consider: 1. the deictic centre may be based on where it will be in the future. If your friend will move to the zoo in the future, he may be taking his future location as the deictic centre with respect to moving towards the zoo, even though he's not there now. 2. The deictic centre can move based on conversational echo: if he takes the zoo as the deictic centre and asks you a question about it, and you repeat most of the words from his question in your answer, you may be more inclined to also echo the deictic centre that he used. It's complicated...

Comment: there is some interesting thing here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deixis#Place

Comment: @AlanCarmack That is a perfectly adequate answer to the question; you should post it as such. (As a side note, getting deictic centres right in foreign languages is one of the hardest things. For a speaker of a Germanic language with their ‘mobile’ deictic centres, for example, it is exceedingly difficult to get used to the fact that in languages like Mandarin, the deictic centre is **always** the speaker, never the listener or anywhere else.)

Comment: If you are currently *at home* & the person you are speaking to is *not* currently at the zoo, it would sound very strange for you to say "I am *coming* to the zoo this evening", even as a response to the question "Are you Coming ... ?".

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet This is tangential, but isn't there a commonly used phrase in Mandarin *wo ma shang guo lai* (I'm immediately coming over), for which the deictic centre is the listener's location? (Note: I don't claim proficiency in Mandarin.)

Comment: @Lawrence Yes, there are certain cases where you wouldn’t normally use 去 _qù_ ‘go’ at all. 过来 _guòlái_ ‘come (on) over’ is one of them; 过去 _guòqù_ instead means ‘pass by, move on, die’. Another one is 起来 _qǐlái_ ‘go/move up(wards)’, which doesn’t have a 去 _qù_ ‘go’ counterpart at all (there is no *起去 _*qǐqù_). But those are a tiny minority, and they’re usually caused by one or the other combination having taken over a deixis-agnostic and often unpredictable meaning and being therefore shunned in its literal sense.

Comment: @TrevorD Perhaps… but in other very similar scenarios not. Imagine, for example, a phone conversation between A and B who are both at their respective homes. A asks B, “Are you coming to C’s party tomorrow night?”. Here, it would be perfectly natural for B to reply, “Of course I’m coming—it’s going to be the party of the year!”. Actually, for the zoo example, I don’t think it would sound so odd either. “Are you coming to the zoo tomorrow?” — “Yeah, I’ll come if I can make it” sounds natural enough to me.

Answer (score 3):

When you want an answer to a question, don't look randomly on the internet and expect enlightenment. **Especially** not for a question on language.

This random extract tries to stuff way too many possibilities into one paragraph. One gets the impression that the author is compressing a complicated phenomenon and scanting on details, which is in fact correct.

If you really want to know what deixis is about, go to the source. [Fillmore's 1971 Santa Cruz Deixis Lectures](http://www.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/Deixis.html) are the basic documents of and the clearest statement of the study of deixis in English.

In particular, [Lecture 5, "Coming and Going"](http://www.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/5-ComingAndGoing.pdf) deals with precisely this problem, in detail. And with many more, and much better-chosen, examples to make clear what's going on.

Comment: Do you have a simple link for beginners like me? The link you provided got too many words.

Comment: The question you provided has too big an answer. You see what happens when you try to put too much information into too few words. Beginners like you need to stop being beginners and actually learn something. Or quit wondering. This is not a site for beginners.

Comment: I just need a few key points. For example, You & your friend are currently at your friend's home. AT the end of conversation, you said "I am going home now". If you said like that, it meant You & your friend both knew that you wanted to leave. Maybe, both just care about leaving & moving to anywhere is not important.

Comment: However, if you said "I am coming to the party tonight". That meant the location of "where you want to go to" is important. This could be that you think the party is important & your saying is focusing on arriving at the party.