# <go to> or <come to>?

Tags: meaning

My wife is very fond of London.

I recently noticed someone saying "She wants to **come to** London" whereas I used to stay "She wants to **go to** London".

Is there a difference between the 2 statements or are they completely exchangeable?

Comment: Duplicate: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10178/i-want-to-come-there-or-i-want-to-go-there

Comment: Duplicate: https://english.stackexchange.com/a/338865/15299

Answer (score 2):

If I am in New York, I say "She wants to go to London."  If I am in London, I say "She wants to come to London".  I use "come" for moving to my location.  Otherwise I use "go".